# how to download google docs document exported as pdf from terminal using wget or curl

Tags: download, wget, google-docs

I'm trying to download my master thesis from google docs as a pdf file..

The ui method (pdf > download > PDF document) fails because of internet connection and the size of the document which is quite big.

I want to download it using wget command from a Linux server which had a good internet connection, I tried a lot of solutions such this [one](https://gist.github.com/iamtekeste/3cdfd0366ebfd2c0d805), but they didn't work..

any help please!

Answer (score 2):

If your server can access the user interface of Docs I strongly recommend you to download the PDF with it to save complexity. If the server doesn't offer that option you could use this curl command below to capture [`Files.export()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) from [`Drive API`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

```bash
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{DOC ID}/export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer {ACCESS TOKEN}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed >> Doc.pdf
```

You'll need an access token for a single use, so could use [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to generate one by selecting the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope and clicking on *Exchange authorization code for tokens*.

Comment: I get a 180b corrupted Doc.pdf file using the curl command